# How do I get these delete cache statements to run depending on what value I got from the below query?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, caching, ssis

I am sort of new to SQL so my apologies in advance:

So... I want to clear my cache (I'm running into frequent memory issues each time I'm trying to load a large batch of data) depending on how much memory my SQL server is taking up:

to clear my cache I would use the following statements:

```
DBCC FreeProcCache
DBCC FreeSystemCache
DBCC FreeSessionCache
```

To obtain the memory usage and display it in some sort of temp table I used the following query:

```
SELECT CAST(physical_memory_in_bytes / (1024.0 * 1024.0 * 1024.0)) AS DECIMAL(20, 2)) AS PhysicalMemoryGB,
   CAST((bpool_committed * 8) / (1024.0 * 1024.0) AS DECIMAL (20, 2)) AS BufferPoolCommittedMemoryGB,
   CAST((bpool_commit_target *8) / (1024.0 * 1024.0) AS DECIMAL (20, 2)) AS BufferPoolTargetMemoryGB,

(
       SELECT CAST(CAST(value_in_use as INT) / 1024.0 AS DECIMAL(20,2))
       FROM sys.configurations
       Where name = 'min server memory (MB)'
)      AS MinServerMemoryGB

(
       SELECT CAST(CAST(value_in_use as INT) / 1024.0 AS DECIMAL(20,2))
       FROM sys.configurations
       Where name = 'max server memory (MB)'
)      AS MaxServerMemoryGB

(   
      SELECT cntr_Value / 1024.0
      FROM sys.dm_os_performance_counters
      WHERE counter_name = 'Total Server Memory (KB)'
)      AS TotalServerMemoryMB
FROM sys.dm_os_sys_info WITH(NOLOCK);
```

Is there any way I can get the DBCC commands to run after getting SQL to check what my memory usage is? Or would I need to set-up SSIS Packages/Jobs?

Comment: Removed the conflicting dbms tags from your question.  Please tag the correct dbms you are using.

Comment: thank you. I am using "SQL Server Management Studio 2008"

Comment: If you cut yourself on a nail every time you walked in your front door, would you keep putting a band aid on every time you walked through the door or would you do something about the nail?

Comment: I'm confused, please explain?

Comment: @JohnLoe He's saying that what you're doing is treating the symptom, not the cause.  You might want to look more into *why* you're running into memory issues.

Comment: I only need a temporary remedy as we will be replacing the old server with a completely new system in a few months. Unfortunately until then we just need to somehow make sure the data is inserted "semi-smoothly". Anyone have any pointers please? :(

Comment: Updating and expanding memory is always an option but unfortunately that is not something we can obtain in the near future...